MSTeams | BotFramework -Forbidden error while using GetTeamChannelsAsync() method
We've encountered an issue with fetching the list of channels from Microsoft Teams using the Bot Framework. Previously, our code was functioning properly, but since a few days i.e.15th April 2024, we've been encountering a 'Forbidden' error.
Here's the error message we're receiving:

Error message:Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' |
{"error":{"code":"ServiceError","message":"Unknown"}}
Error Details: at
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.TeamsOperations.GetResponseAsync[T](String
apiUrl, String httpMethod, String invocationId, Object content,
Dictionary2 customHeaders, String continuationToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.TeamsOperations.FetchChannelListWithHttpMessagesAsync(String teamId, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken
cancellationToken) at
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.TeamsOperationsExtensions.FetchChannelListAsync(ITeamsOperations
operations, String teamId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams.TeamsInfo.GetTeamChannelsAsync(ITurnContext
turnContext, String teamId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.WelcomeUserBot.OnInstallationUpdateAddAsync(ITurnContext`1
turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

The specific code causing the issue is:
var teamChannelDetails = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamChannelsAsync(turnContext);

Interestingly, when we point our local ngrok URL to the bot service, everything works fine. However, once we deploy the bot service API on Azure App Service, the error occurs consistently.
We haven't made any changes to our codebase recently, so it's unclear whether this issue stems from a change on Microsoft's end or if it's related to our deployment environment.
We are seeing the same behaviors across all of out bots.
Any assistance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Note: This is occurring on the new Teams instance, on old its working.

Please check the behaviour in both new and old teams.

@RajeeshMenoth Yes this is working with old teams. Thanks for your comment. But do you know the reason for this or is there any workaround to handle this for new Teams Instance?

I have seen such types of issues for new teams on the bot side. These issues can be fixed by Microsoft. You can raise a support ticket to receive assistance.

Hello @Rajeesh Menoth
Could you please refer this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/b29d9cc9e7fd775dcd39af5ae7ee34deefc8a3c3/samples/msteams-application-qbot/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.QBot.Web/Bot/QBotTeamInfo.cs#L57

@SwapnilChowkekar can refer the sample given by vikram

@RajeeshMenoth, I asked Microsoft for support on this issue. One of their guys emailed me that they have pushed few updates. Not sure what the updates are, but the issue seems to be resolved. i.e. I am getting the channel list.
